# Apollo client and graphQl query error : Variable '$where' expected value of type 'OrganizationWhereUniqueInput

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-client, prisma

Hi I'm making a backend server with GraphQL, Apollo client & Prisma. I'm trying to write a query where I get organization data back. The user who sends the query should get its organization data back based on their id. When running the query in playground I get this error.

error:

```
"message": "Variable '$where' expected value of type 'OrganizationWhereUniqueInput!' but got: {\"employees\":{\"id\":\"ckas83z13t9qk0992pucglc4k\"}}. Reason: 'employees' Field 'employees' is not defined in the input type 'OrganizationWhereUniqueInput'. (line 1, column 8):\nquery ($where: OrganizationWhereUniqueInput!) {\n       ^",
```

I don't see what I did wrong. I'm still pretty new to it all. I tried to write the function in `Query.js` in different ways but no luck.  Also, I still find the error messages you get in playground very confusing

schema:

```
type Query {
    getOrganization: Organization!
}

type Organization {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    country: String!
    street: String!
    zipCode: Int!
    houseNumber: Int!
    addings: String
    employees: [User!]

}

type User {
    id: ID!
    firstname:String!
    lastname:String!
    email: String!
    services: [Service!]
    organization: Organization!
}
```

query.js

```
function getOrganization(parent, args, context, info){
    const userId = getUserId(context)
        return context.prisma.organization({employees:{id:userId}})   
}

// also tried this 
/*
function getOrganization(parent, args, context, info){
    const userId = getUserId(context)
        return context.prisma.organization({where: {employees:{id:userId}}})   
}*/
```

User.js

```
function services (parent, args, context){
    return context.prisma.user({id: parent.id}).services()
}

function organization (parent, args, context){
    return context.prisma.user({id: parent.id}).organization()
}


module.exports={
    services,
    organization
}
```

Organization.js

```
function employees(parent, args, context){
    return context.prisma.organization({id: parent.id}).employees()
}

module.exports={
    employees
}
```

Could anyone help me see what went wrong?

query in playground:

```
query{
  getOrganization{
    name 
    id 
  }}

HTTP HEADER:

{
  "Authorization": "Bearer {contains user token }"
}
```

Comment: Could you share the query you made as well?

Comment: Okay I've edited my question so it contains the playground query

Comment: I think you cannot use the variable  `employees` to query for a specific organziation. The error states the same: `OrganizationWhereUniqueInput` this input might only be accepting the organization ID as an input so this query `return context.prisma.organization({employees:{id:userId}})` will have to be changed to `return context.prisma.organization({ {id: 'some-id' })`

Comment: Okay, but there must be a way to get back the organization that the user is part of ?

Comment: Could you try fetching the organization via the employee like this: `function getOrganization(parent, args, context, info){
    const userId = getUserId(context)
        return context.prisma.user( {id: userId }).organization() 
}
`

Answer (score 0):

Just use *OrganizationWhereInput* instead of *OrganizationWhere**Unique**Input*. It will return a list of organisations instead of a single result (might return an empty array), yet it should allow you to search for an organisation using an employee id.